# How to convert unicode into string in android

Tags: android, unicode

I want to convert unicode string to string. I faced may method. But i did not get any useful answer for me. For example, If i send "b'day" string on server ,then i get "b’day" string from server . How to check comming string from server is string or unicode string.
If you know, Please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: i send b'day string on server,when i get that string b&#8217;day

Answer (score 1):

For that you'll have to :

1. Parse the text into the separate unicode digits.
2. Then do Integer.ParseInt(XXXX, 16) to get a hex value.
3. Then `switch case` that to char to get the actual character.

   ```
   String str = myString.split(" ")[0];
   str = str.replace("\\","");
   String[] array = str.split("u");
   String stringText = "";
   for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
       int hexValue = Integer.parseInt(array[i], 16);
       stringText += (char)hexValue;
   }
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(stringText));
   ```

`&#8217;` is the `Html` representation for **( ' )** in `Unicode`.

You can get your desired output by `Html.fromHtml(stringText)`

Comment: @Manoj Kumar **b&#8217;day** this is the string that you get?

Comment: @ManojKumar try this way Html.fromHtml("b&#8217;day")